# Android Studio barcode scanner how to add to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Zxing barcode scanner on my app. The result handler when the user scanned the barcode was originally to show the barcode number ina popup on the screen. I want to change this and instead bring the user to a new page where they can see the barcode number and add extra details too like product name, date, category etc. Then when the user clicks save it should add to the firebase database and the barcode number should become the ID. 
Then the next time the user scans the same barcode the app will recognise it and show the details you already added.

Here is my code:

```
public class BarcodeDetect extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
private static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    //our database reference object
    DatabaseReference databaseFoods;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(scannerView);
    //getting the reference of artists node
    databaseFoods = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foods");
int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if(currentApiVersion >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    if(checkPermission())
    {
        Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        requestPermission();
    }
}
}
private boolean checkPermission()
{
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BarcodeDetect.this, CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

private void requestPermission()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (cameraAccepted){
                    Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else

                    {
                    Toast.makeText(BarcodeDetect.this, "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA},
                                                        REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(BarcodeDetect.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            if(scannerView == null) {
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                setContentView(scannerView);
            }
            scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            scannerView.startCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(BarcodeDetect.this, viewBarcode.class);

    //starting the activity with intent
    startActivity(intent);
//        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
//        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(BarcodeDetect.this);
//            }
//        });
//        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myResult));
//                startActivity(browserIntent);
//            }
//        });
//        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
//        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
//        alert1.show();
    }
    }
```

I have commented out the original code in the event handler and added my own code to bring you to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

This can be thought as a 2 step process:

1. Pass the data to the next activity
2. Validate if the data exist in the
   database

Once you get the codebar pass it to the next Activity using `putExta` method

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY", result.getText());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in the second activity get the extra and validate if it is available in the RTD

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
    String codebar = getIntent().getStringExtra("SOME_KEY");
    //Once you get the codebar use it as key to query on the Firebase RTD
    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    root.child("products").child(codebar).addValueEventListener(...
        //Auto generated methods
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                 //Show the user the data
          } else {
                //Ask the user to fill a form and upload the data to the same node you are asking for
          }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will i still need this code in the result handler?  final String myResult = result.getText();
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
        Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        I

Comment: It seems not because you only needed the scanned barcode. And regarding your second question, if the snapshot doesn't exist, that mean the product has not being created in the database, you have to provide the user with an UI to upload a product to the database.